# Get request working fine. Post request is not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, post, axios

[image: this is the screenshot of the error]

My POST method looks like this.

```
let sendingData = [this.deviceData.CustomerName, this.deviceData.machine, this.$route.params.id,  this.deviceData.additionaltitle, transactiontype, sendingfeeedback];
            axios.post(this.baseurl + 'newOrder', sendingData,
            {
              headers:
              {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  
              }
            }
             ).then((data) =>
            {
              console.log(data);
            }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
            //alert("The Order has been sent");
            this.clearData();
```

I have also disabled CSRF TOKEN in the middleware. Can anyone help me to fix this post request? I am using Vue in the front end and laravel in the backend.
My routes

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');

Route::get('device',[DeviceController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('fleet/{id}',[FeedbackController::class, 'getItems']);
Route::post('fleet/newOrder',[FeedbackController::class, 'orderNewMachine']);
Route::post('fleet/newService',[FeedbackController::class, 'orderService']);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you share routes?

Comment: message: server Error

Comment: Is your `APP_DEBUG= true` in your environment file ? @RajKumar

Comment: No it is false.

Answer (score 0):

let sendingData must be object not array.

let sendingData = { CustomerName: this.deviceData.CustomerName, machine: this.deviceData.machine, id: this.$route.params.id,  additionaltitle: this.deviceData.additionaltitle, transactiontype:transactiontype, sendingfeeedback: sendingfeeedback }

Comment: Hi Orujov! I change array to Object and it still is not working. Thank you for this correction.